# Reinventing the basic calculator functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, calculator

I decided to reinvent the basic calculator functions using only:

- the set of positive integers
- greater than, less than, and equality properties
- increment and decrement

(in other words, the counting on fingers method)

```
def is_positive_int(x):
    if type(x) == int and x >= 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def add(x,y):
    if is_positive_int(x) and is_positive_int(y):
        for i in range(y):
            x += 1
        return x
    else: 
        return False

def multiply(x,y):
    if is_positive_int(y) and is_positive_int(y):
        m = 0
        for i in range(y):
            m = add(m,x)
        return m
    else: 
        return False

def power(x,y):
    """ x to the y power """
    if is_positive_int(x) and is_positive_int(y):
        p = 1
        for i in range(y):
            p = multiply(p,x)
        return p
    else: 
        return False

def subtract(x,y):
    """ x - y """
    if is_positive_int(x) and is_positive_int(y) and x > y:
        for i in range(y):
            x -= 1
        return x
    else: 
        return False

def divide(x,y):
    """ x / y """
    if is_positive_int(x) and is_positive_int(y):
        floor = 0 
        remainder = 0
        for i in range(x):
            remainder += 1
            if remainder == y:
                floor += 1
                remainder = 0
        return {'floor':floor, 'modulus':remainder}
    else: 
        return False

def floor(x,y):
    """ a // b"""
    return divide(x,y)['floor']


def modulus(x,y):
    """ x % y"""
    return divide(x,y)['modulus']
```

Comment: Instead of `if type(x) == int` you could've use `isinstance(x, int)`. It's not that `isinstance` is good, mind you — it's just less bad than checking equality of types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say you have this situation:

```
if ...:
    ...
    return ...
else:
    return ...
```

What if the `if` condition is True?  Some statements will be executed, and then the function will return.  In other words, if the condition is True, execution never leaves the `if` block.  Therefore, you really don't need the `else`.  Just put the return directly under the `if`:

```
if ...:
    ...
    return ...
return ...
```

---

It is generally a bad idea to use the pattern `type(...) == ...`.  Usually, we use `isinstance(..., ...)`.  That way, subclasses are allowed.  Of course, you might keep it if you don't want subclasses to be allowed, but I don't see a reason to restrict the user.  I'm assuming you want only integers because only integers can be passed to `range`, but subclasses of integers can indeed also be passed.  For example, booleans are integers.  `range(False, True)` is perfectly valid.  Also, `True + False + False` is valid, so it won't mess up your arithmetic.  That makes your `is_positive_int` function look like this:

```
def is_positive_int(x):
    if isinstance(x, int) and x >= 0:
        return True
    return False
```

But what do you see?  If a condition is True, we return True.  If it is False, we return False.  In other words, we are really just returning the condition, so why not do it like this:

```
def is_positive_int(x):
    return isinstance(x, int) and x >= 0
```

---

I see a very similar pattern in all of your functions:

```
if is_positive_int(x) and is_positive_int(y):
    ...
else:
    return False
```

First of all, we can remember what I mentioned earlier about not leaving the `if` block unless the condition is False.  Therefore, I would actually switch the `if` and `else`:

```
if not is_positive_int(x) or not is_positive_int(y):
    return False
...
```

We remove a level of nesting that way.  The problem is that we use the same code in a bunch of different functions, so we can make a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators).  A decorator is a function which, when given another function (`a`) to wrap, returns a wrapper function (`b`) for `a`.  `b` overrides `a` and does its special thing, but it usually calls `a` later.  This is my idea:

```
def guarantee_positive(function):
    # Each function takes two arguments
    def wrapper(x, y):
        if is_positive_int(x) and is_positive_int(y):
            # Deal with it normally
            return function(x, y)
        return False
    # Now wrapper(x, y) will be called instead of function(x, y)
    return wrapper
```

To use it, add `@guarantee_positive` before each function definition.  For example:

```
@guarantee_positive
def divide(x, y):
    floor = 0
    remainder = 0
    for i in range(x):
        remainder += 1
        if remainder == y:
            floor += 1
            remainder = 0
    return {'floor': floor, 'modulus': remainder}
```

That makes for a much cleaner function.  Of course, `subtract` has an extra condition, but I'll get to that later.

---

With all that about function decorators, why do you need them both to be positive?  I can see why you might want `y` to be positive: because `range` doesn't work the same with negative numbers, but you aren't using `i` most of the time, so just use the absolute value of `y`.  I'll give an example:

```
def multiply(x, y):
    m = 0
    function = add if y > 0 else subtract
    for _ in range(abs(y)):
        m = function(m, x)
    return m
```

It doesn't require a decorator, and it is capable of more.  You can now use it with any combination of negative and positive:

```
-3,  3 -> -9
-3, -3 ->  9
 3, -3 -> -9
 3,  3 ->  9
```

Your `add` function would be like this:

```
def add(x, y):
    # Add 1 if y is positive; subtract 1 if it is negative
    y_add = (1 if y >= 0 else -1)
    for _ in range(abs(y)):
        x += y_add
    return x
```

Again, it's shorter than the original, and it does more.

There are some functions where it isn't quite that easy.  For example, `power()` would be difficult to implement a negative `y` (`x` doesn't need to be positive even with the current implementation), but most of the others don't need the decorator.  I won't tell you all of them, but I have given examples of the more common hangups.

---

Back to the decorator, I think it is better to raise an exception when something is wrong than to return `False`.  After all, they are called exceptions for a reason.  Normally, the function does one thing, but there are exceptions (or there should be).

---

I see a lot of `for i in range(y)` when `i` isn't used.  The common way of signifying that `i` is just a place holder is using `_` as the variable name.

---

It looks like you cheated with `divide()` :)  You don't actually have division, you have [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod).  I think a name similar to that would be more appropriate.  another thing is that you return a dictionary.  I prefer something closer to how the built-in function does it:

```
return floor, remainder
```

That way, you can do:

```
floor, remainder = divide(...)
```

Instead of the equivalent:

```
result = divide(...)
floor, remainder = result['float'], result['modulus']
```

Either one should have a doc string that explains what the return value is.  If I called `divide(...)` when it had a doc string of just `x / y`, I would assume that I would get `x / y`, not a dictionary with the floored result and the remainder.  Your `floor` and `modulus` functions would then be:

```
def floor(x, y):
    """a // b"""
    return divide(x, y)[0]

def modulus(x, y):
    """x % y"""
    return divide(x, y)[1]
```

Except that `divide` will hopefully have a more descriptive name.

I did notice that `floor` is inside of `divide()`, but I am assuming that is just a typo.

---

You seem to be following [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) fairly well, but I noticed that you don't have any whitespace between the key-value pairs in your dictionary.  PEP 8 recommends that you put a space between the colon and the value.  I don't see it in the PEP, but I think you should put a space between a comma and the following object.  For example:

```
def divide(x, y):
```

not

```
def divide(x,y):
```

Without the space, it feels smooshed, like you're golfing (code golfing, not with a golf club).

Answer (score 6):

Why not go a step further and implement this as a class, this way you learn something about magic methods as well :)

```
class Fingers(int):
    """A class implementing counting with fingers instead of the more effective built-in int methods"""

    def __init__(self, x):
        if not isinstance(x, int):
            raise TypeError("Input must be 'int' (or subclass)")
        self.x = x

    def __pos__(self):
        return self

    def __neg__(self):
        return Fingers(-self.x)

    def __abs__(self):
        return Fingers(abs(self.x))

    def __add__(self, other):
        """a + b, a and b may be negative"""
        y_add = (1 if other >= 0 else -1)
        x = self.x
        for _ in range(abs(other)):
            x += y_add
        return Fingers(x)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self + (-other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        """a * b, a and b may be negative"""
        m = Fingers(0)
        for _ in range(abs(other)):
            m = m + self
        return m

    def __pow__(self, exponent):
        """a**b, b must be positive"""
        if exponent < 0:
            raise NotImplementedError
        p = Fingers(1)
        for _ in range(y):
            p = p * self
        return p

    def __divmod__(self, other):
        floor = Fingers(0)
        remainder = Fingers(0)
        for _ in range(self):
            remainder = remainder + Fingers(1)
            if remainder == other:
                floor = floor + Fingers(1)
                remainder = Fingers(0)
        return floor, remainder

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        """a//b"""
        return self.__divmod__(other)[0]

    def __mod__(self, other):
        """a%b"""
        return self.__divmod__(other)[1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Fingers(3)
    y = Fingers(2)
    assert x + y == Fingers(5)
    assert x * y == Fingers(6)
    assert x**y == Fingers(9)
    assert divmod(x, y) == (Fingers(1), Fingers(1))
    assert x // y == Fingers(1)
    assert x % y == Fingers(1)
```

(I did not implement `__iadd__` etc, so `x += 3` will not work. They are trivial to implement, though.)

Comment: There was a decorator or maybe a base class that allowed you to implement only some operators; reflected and in-place would be filled in automagically, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Found it! [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) is the name.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been said that you should've probably implemented this as a class. There's even [something](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations) in the docs about that.

However, there's also one concept you could've made use of: [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding).

You could make your numbers have something like `.to_church()` method, so that `CustomNumeral(3).to_church(f)` would return something similar to `lambda x: f(f(f(x)))`, it allows for very expressive illustration for how addition naturally arises from incrementing and multiplication - from addition.

Comment: `Hozier.to_church()`  `print Hozier.sins` `sharpenKnife()` `return deathlessDeath`